# Prove that for all $x, y \in H, ||Px - Py|| \leq ||x - y||$, for a closed convex nonempty subset of Hilbert space...

Tags: real-analysis

For a closed convex nonempty subset $K$ of a Hilbert space $H$ and $x \in H$, denote by $Px \in K$ a unique closest point to $x$ among points in $K$, i.e. $Px \in K$ such that

$||Px - x|| \leq ||y - x||, \forall y \in K$.

First show that such point $Px$ exists and is unique. Then prove that for all $x, y \in H, ||Px - Py|| \leq ||x - y||$.

Comment: This is a standard result and you see the proof in http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~razk/iWeb/My_Site/Teaching_files/Hilbert.pdf

Comment: That's a great document, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 1.9 and corollary 1.22 in the document/link provided by xpaul contain the proof for this question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/731949)

Comment: That's a good point - finding exactly what you need, only to face a broken link is never fun.  I will write out the answer too.